# I get overwhelmed while self studying courses. What can I do when I can't sit in classes anymore?

Tags: postdocs, coursework

I am learning a new numerical modeling technique (molecular dynamics) that requires learning graduate level maths and physics concepts. I am learning from youTube videos and books. However, I am getting all overwhelmed and am retaining nothing.

I am feeling disappointed because I am not able to grasp the subject that is very important for my postdoc success. My entire postdoc contract is based on the assumption that I can learn this in 6 months and produce results in the next 6 months.

I cannot sit through classes as postdocs are not allowed to do so in my university. I have access to online materials only.

I am feeling super stressed out and overwhelmed. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Reading and watching videos is not a substitute for learning. Treat the material like you would if you were in a class. Find exercises that you can do to assure that you have "mastered" the material. Take notes. Make checkpoints at which you can assess your progress. You learn from reinforcement and feedback. The latter is hard in online learning. Find someone who can give you some feedback and answer questions. Find a working group if possible and learn it as a group, reinforcing one another.

I wonder, also, whether you can informally sit in on a course while not taking it. A friendly professor might permit it and even let you take exams informally. I've done this as a professor, actually, when wanting to learn the basics of a new field.

Answer (score 0):

As Buffy said, reading books and watching videos, although you will learn a bit, is not a good way of learning. There are many different substitutes that will actually help you. When watching videos (as you have been doing), just sitting and watching won't help you. You need a way to retain that information. That could be taking notes, typing on a google doc, making bullet points, etc. You should also always have goals in mind. If you have goals, you have something to push too. I have found that making goals are very helpful when learning something overwhelming. Taking it one step at a time.

If you have a friend that is good at this topic, ask him/her for questions. Don't be afraid to ask! I have found that asking family and friends for help really helps you out.

Some other things that could help you not get overwhelmed are:

- Breathe and take frequent brain breaks. If your brain is constantly working, you will get tired and start seeing blurrily.
- Take a walk, being outside with nature is scientifically proven to calm you down.
- Get better sleep, being overwhelmed does not mean you have to stay up all night trying to understand a topic. Your body needs sleep!
- Focus, don't get distracted by funny cats during your youtube video lessons. Always stay on topic.

Hope this helps :)